# How to sort a column using regex in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, sorting

In the 'New Cases' column, I have approximately the following values:

`+10 000`, `+ 1000`, `+ 100` and `+ 10, 0`.

My code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv('Covid-19.csv')
a = iris['New Cases'].str.contains[r'+[d{5}]']
iris.sort_values(a)
```

Stack trace:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input42-291424a61469> in <module>
        2 import pandas as pd
        3 iris = pd.read_csv('Covid-19.csv')
------> 4 a = iris['New Cases'].str.contains[r'+[d{5}]']
        5 iris.sort_values(a)

TypeError 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: should be `iris['a'] = iris['New Cases'].str.contains(r'+[d{5}]'); iris.sort_values('a')`.

Comment: You need to use `.contains(r'\+\d{5}')` if you want to find matches starting with `+` and then having 5 digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It turned out, but gives a bool value, how to make numbers?

Comment: What do you mean? `iris['New Cases'].str.extract(r'(\+\d{5})')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I got this: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hfOhHFpU6NqAjYfZfjBGKQ5eG-GbcrIg) but i need numbers (dtype: int)

Comment: If you need help, post the sample of your df in the question. Images do not help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   [here is the screenshot of the data frame, and the file itself](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bWM7xHjCevb6beaN_PS898U-_ocFsI4h)

Comment: Ok, try `iris['New Cases'] = iris['New Cases'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int)`

Comment: IMHO, the question has all details needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
iris['New Cases'] = iris['New Cases'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int)
```

First, you need to cast the data to string type (`.astype(str)`), then remove all chars that are not digits (`.str.replace(r'\D+', '')`), and then cast the result to an int (with `.astype(int)`).

Python pandas test:

```
data = { 'New Cases': ['+1,370', '+6,740', '+1,159', 0, '+9,625']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['New Cases'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int)
#    0    1370
#    1    6740
#    2    1159
#    3       0
#    4    9625
#    Name: New Cases, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.DataFrame.str.contains` is a method so you need to call it. Try:

```py
iris['New Cases'].str.contains(r'+[d{5}]')
```

Comment: This throws *`re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0`*

Comment: It's because a copy-pasted his regex, without checking if it was well defined. It's not.